# Homeomorphisms of different spheres

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, geometric-topology

It is pretty straightforward to show that if $X$ is a Banach space under two equivalent norms, then the respective open unit balls $B_1$ and $B_2$ are homeomorphic only by showing that $B_i$ is homeomorphic to $X$ (*e.g.* via $x\mapsto {\rm tan}(\frac{\pi}{2}\|x\|)x$).

> Can we show that the unit spheres (defined in terms of two equivalent norms) are homeomorphic to each other?

I am interested mainly in the finite-dimensional case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finite (fixed) dimension all the norms are equivalent.
The function
$$x\longmapsto\frac{x}{\|x\|_2}$$
is continuous and bijective form $S_1$ (compact by Heine-Borel) to $S_2$, so the inverse is continuous.